# rm with variables: one works, the next does not

Tags: linux, bash

This is really driving me crazy. I have read and tried other question/answers like:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/823623/rm-works-on-command-line-but-not-in-script
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326584/rm-command-in-bash-script-does-not-work-with-variable
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326597

But I cannot get it to work. The most strange part is, that the first 'rm' works nicely, but the second does nothing.

I am making a git-hook, to update custom files in Directadmin.

My script start with

```
#!/bin/bash
dirDaBase="/usr/local/directadmin/"
dirDeploy="/path/to/source/files/"
```

First part that works nice:

```
#### de custom files
###########################################################################
dirDA="${dirDaBase}data/templates/custom/"
dirSource="${dirDeploy}data/templates/"

showTitle "Deploy custom files to ${dirDA}"
showDir $dirDA

show "remove old files"
sudo rm -fv "${dirDA}"*.* 2>&1 | showResult
showDir $dirDA

sudo cp "${dirSource}"*.* "${dirDA}" 2>&1 | showResult

fixPermissionsFromRoot $dirDA diradmin diradmin
showReady "custom files"
```

NB! Normally I use `rm -rf`

The `showXX` and `fixPerm...` are helper functions

We always end path-variables with a slash...

In the next part `rm` does not work.
The `dirDA` did not work wíth the ending-slash. And because of reading the other question/answers, I removed the ending-slash from the next `dirDA`, hoping that would solve it, but it did not.... :-(

I tried several formats... as you can see

```
#### custom scripts
###########################################################################
dirDA="${dirDaBase}scripts/custom"
dirSource="${dirDeploy}data/scripts/"

showTitle "Deploy scripts to ${dirDA}"
showDir $dirDA

show "remove old scripts try 1"
#without quotes
sudo rm -v $dirDA/*.sh 2>&1 | showResult
showDir $dirDA
show "remove old scripts try 2"
#with quotes and *.sh
sudo rm -v "${dirDA}"/*.sh 2>&1 | showResult
showDir $dirDA
show "remove old scripts try 3"
#with quotes and *.*
sudo rm -v "${dirDA}"/*.* 2>&1 | showResult
showDir $dirDA

sudo cp "${dirSource}"*.sh "${dirDA}"/ 2>&1 | showResult

fixPermissionsFromRoot $dirDA diradmin diradmin
showReady "scripts"
```

**Output from first part:**

```
************************************
deploy files to DA
************************************
Deploy custom files to /usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/
total 112
drwxr-xr-x   2 diradmin diradmin  4096 May 18 13:32 .
drwx--x--x. 10 diradmin diradmin  4096 May 16 10:33 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 diradmin diradmin   106 May 18 13:32 cust_nginx.CUSTOM.1.post
  <....>
-rw-r--r--   1 diradmin diradmin  4431 May 18 13:32 rhBasic_paths.map.conf

remove old files
removed ‘/usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/cust_nginx.CUSTOM.1.post’
  <....>
removed ‘/usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/rhBasic_paths.map.conf’

list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   2 diradmin diradmin    6 May 18 13:35 .
drwx--x--x. 10 diradmin diradmin 4096 May 16 10:33 ..


************************************
Fix root permissions to diradmin:diradmin
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/
total 112
drwxr-xr-x   2 diradmin diradmin  4096 May 18 13:35 .
drwx--x--x. 10 diradmin diradmin  4096 May 16 10:33 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       106 May 18 13:35 cust_nginx.CUSTOM.1.post
  <....>
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root      4431 May 18 13:35 rhBasic_paths.map.conf
fixed root permissions
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/data/templates/custom/
total 112
drwxr-xr-x   2 diradmin diradmin  4096 May 18 13:35 .
drwx--x--x. 10 diradmin diradmin  4096 May 16 10:33 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 diradmin diradmin   106 May 18 13:35 cust_nginx.CUSTOM.1.post
  <....>
-rw-r--r--   1 diradmin diradmin  4431 May 18 13:35 rhBasic_paths.map.conf
Ready fixPermissions
------------------------------------
Ready custom files
------------------------------------
```

**Output from second part:**

```
************************************
Deploy scripts to /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
total 20
drwx------  2 diradmin diradmin   76 May 18 12:59 .
drwx--x--x. 4 diradmin diradmin 4096 Apr 25 11:43 ..
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  161 May 18 13:32 domain_create_post.sh
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin 6295 Apr  4 17:38 README
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  158 May 18 13:32 user_create_post.sh

remove old scripts try 1
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/*.sh’: No such file or directory
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
total 20
drwx------  2 diradmin diradmin   76 May 18 12:59 .
drwx--x--x. 4 diradmin diradmin 4096 Apr 25 11:43 ..
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  161 May 18 13:32 domain_create_post.sh
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin 6295 Apr  4 17:38 README
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  158 May 18 13:32 user_create_post.sh

remove old scripts try 2
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/*.sh’: No such file or directory
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
total 20
drwx------  2 diradmin diradmin   76 May 18 12:59 .
drwx--x--x. 4 diradmin diradmin 4096 Apr 25 11:43 ..
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  161 May 18 13:32 domain_create_post.sh
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin 6295 Apr  4 17:38 README
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  158 May 18 13:32 user_create_post.sh

remove old scripts try 3
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/*.*’: No such file or directory
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
total 20
drwx------  2 diradmin diradmin   76 May 18 12:59 .
drwx--x--x. 4 diradmin diradmin 4096 Apr 25 11:43 ..
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  161 May 18 13:32 domain_create_post.sh
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin 6295 Apr  4 17:38 README
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  158 May 18 13:32 user_create_post.sh

************************************
Fix root permissions to diradmin:diradmin
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
total 20
drwx------  2 diradmin diradmin   76 May 18 12:59 .
drwx--x--x. 4 diradmin diradmin 4096 Apr 25 11:43 ..
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  161 May 18 13:35 domain_create_post.sh
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin 6295 Apr  4 17:38 README
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  158 May 18 13:35 user_create_post.sh
fixed root permissions
list files from: /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom
total 20
drwx------  2 diradmin diradmin   76 May 18 12:59 .
drwx--x--x. 4 diradmin diradmin 4096 Apr 25 11:43 ..
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  161 May 18 13:35 domain_create_post.sh
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin 6295 Apr  4 17:38 README
-rwx------  1 diradmin diradmin  158 May 18 13:35 user_create_post.sh
Ready fixPermissions
------------------------------------
Ready scripts
------------------------------------
```

What, o what am I doing wrong?? (I hope it is not a stupid typo)

I know I can also use find and grep etc. as told in the other answers. But then why is the first working and the second script is not?

Thanks in advance, flexJoly

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions.

Comment: I tried with ánd without :-( (look at try 2 and try3)

Comment: You need +rx on the directories to delete contents by glob, whether or not you use `sudo`. This is because five are expanded by the current shell.

Comment: @thatotherguy WOW!! tx!! that is it! Although it seems to be only needed inside the script and not in cli. Strange. Please can you add this as answer, so I can select it. I do not understand what you mean by: "This is because five are expanded by the current shell." Super thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type

```
sudo rm /my/dir/*
```

The current shell is responsible for expanding the pattern and actually run

```
sudo rm /my/dir/file1 /my/dir/file2
```

This means that the current user must have access to enumerate the files. Since this happens *before* running `sudo`, the root access you'd get *after* running `sudo` does not apply.

Some workarounds include:

```
# Run a shell as root, which can in turn expand the pattern
sudo bash -c 'rm /my/dir/*'

# Run a command that does not rely on the current shell to enumerate files
sudo find /my/dir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work with GNU sed:-

```
find "${dirDA}"\*.sh > stack

while [ $(wc -l stack | cut -d' ' -f1) -gt 0 ]
do
filename=$(sed -n '1p' stack)
sudo rm -v "${filename}" 2>&1 | showResult
sed -i '1d' stack
done
```

This uses find to make a list of the files to be deleted, outputs them into a stack file, pulls them off the stack, and deletes them one by one with rm.

Whenever I am working with multiple files, I find it easier to set up a loop like this, because that way each file gets treated individually, and I don't have to worry about how rm or whatever other command is going to interpret masks, or whether it will trip up on them.